# How to use tables as options of a schoice exercise in r exams?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, r-exams

I want to create an `schoice` exercise where each of the five options is a table with a CDF, like this one:

[image]

I do not want to provide tables as image. I came across a possibility:

creating a list with 5 tables:

```
sc$questions <- c(rbind(c("F(x)","1")) |> kableExtra::kbl(format = 'latex', col.names = c("","1")),
                  rbind(c("F(x)","2")) |> kableExtra::kbl(format = 'latex', col.names = c("","1")),
                  rbind(c("F(x)","3")) |> kableExtra::kbl(format = 'latex', col.names = c("","1")),
                  rbind(c("F(x)","4")) |> kableExtra::kbl(format = 'latex', col.names = c("","1")),
                  rbind(c("F(x)","5")) |> kableExtra::kbl(format = 'latex', col.names = c("","1")))
```

And then print them using:

````
```{r questionlist, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
answerlist(sc$questions, markup = "markdown")
````

However, this solution only works if I set `kbl()`format to `latex`, I would like to use `pandoc` to set it adequately with math mode (e.g., `colnames` with "\leq").

Comment: The image in your question has no background. It is really hard to read in dark mode, just fyi :)

Comment: Thank you, Dugnom. It was my ultimate solution in case I did not have the possibility to use proper formated tables. Images without background color would do it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came accross this solution:

```r
sc <- list()
sc$questions <- c(rbind(c("$F(x)$","$0$","$\\frac{1}{6}$","$\\frac{1}{2}$","$1$")) |> kable("latex", booktabs=TRUE, align = "c", escape = F, col.names = c("","$x<1$","$1\\leq x<2$","$2\\leq x<3$","$x\\geq 3$")),
                    rbind(c("$F(x)$","$0$","$\\frac{1}{6}$","$\\frac{1}{2}$","$1$")) |> kable("latex", booktabs=TRUE, align = "c", escape = F, col.names = c("","$x\\leq 1$","$1<x\\leq 2$","$2< x\\leq 3$","$x> 3$")),
                    rbind(c("$f(x)$","$\\frac{1}{6}$","$\\frac{1}{2}$","$1$")) |> kable("latex", booktabs=TRUE, align = "c", escape = F, col.names = c("","$x=1$","$x=2$","$x=3$")),
                    rbind(c("$F(x)$","$0$","$\\frac{1}{6}$","$\\frac{1}{2}$","$1$")) |> kable("latex", booktabs=TRUE, align = "c", escape = F, col.names = c("","$x=0$","$x=1$","$x=2$","$x=3$")),
                    rbind(c("$f(x)$","$\\frac{1}{6}$","$\\frac{2}{6}$","$\\frac{3}{6}$")) |> kable("latex", booktabs=TRUE, align = "c", escape = F, col.names = c("","$x=1$","$x=2$","$x=3$")))
```

And:

````
```{r questionlist, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
answerlist(sc$questions, markup = "markdown")
````

Which produced:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Each element of the "answerlist" internally gets collapsed into a single character line when read into R. This is no problem when the table is formatted in LaTeX or HTML because they don't rely on specific line breaks to do the formatting. But plain Markdown formatting gets messed up and is not rendered anymore correctly.

So one option would be to use `match_exams_call()` inside the exercise template to decide whether to produce the finished table, e.g., rendered by `kable`, as LaTeX or HTML.

Another option (and this is what I typically do) is to show all tables inside the "question" with some labels (say A, B, .., E) and then to put only the letters A, ..., E into the "answerlist".